# What is the right way to implement a loading screen in cocos2d-js?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-js

We have two scenes that are loaded with heavy computation; a map screen and a puzzle screen. When we change the scene from A to B, the app gets stuck on scene A for a while before it renders scene B.

So to avoid confusion, we created a dummy scene with 'Loading...' written on it and then on it's onEnter function we change to scene B. The game now gets stuck on the dummy loading scene now instead. But the loading scene takes in touch inputs and the device's native button inputs and triggers it as soon as scene B enters. So the map scrolls if you swipe on the loading scene and puzzle takes input on tapping the loading screen.

Has anyone implemented a proper loading scene with cocos2d-js?